# Order of an element in quotient group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ is normal in $G$ and let $a\in H$. Suppose that the order of class of $\bar a \in G/H$ is finite.
Prove that $o(\bar a) = n$ if and only if $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that
$a^n \in H$.

I was trying to solve this problem. But there is one thing I couldn't figure out. Can't we just say n must naturally be equal to 1. Because H is a group and group must be closed under multiplication.

The solution if I don't consider this thing would be:
Let $\bar a$ denotes class of a, $o(\bar a)=n \implies 1 = \bar a^n = \bar{a^n}$ because $n$ is order of $o(\bar a)$ no integer less then n satisfies this equality.

I am not familiar with latex, sorry for bad notation.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Why should we say that $n=1$? Try an example for $G$ and $H$, e.g., $G=D_n$ and $H=\langle r\rangle\cong C_n$.

Comment: Why are you saying $a \in H$?  That makes $n= 1$ and the problem is utterly trivial and pointless. You should have $a \in G$, *not* $a \in H$.  Then the problem has some worthwhile content.

Comment: This is one of the problems that are close to a tautology. That means, definitions and keeping proof directions apart are all that count. So please be very precise with both. One direction is: Given $n=\min\{k\, : \,a^k\in H\}.$ The other direction is $\operatorname{ord}(\overline{a})=n.$ So you must be clear about how the order is defined, what the abbreviation "overline" means, especially what $\overline{0}$ means, and - what you already wrote - where to use that "overline" is a group homomorphism.

Comment: The question was given wrong as KCd said. Then all things are fine.